# Pulling data from another website

Tags: javascript, html, web, web-scraping

I'm building a troubleshooting site and am looking for a way to pull info directly from the OEM websites. An example would be instructions for a master reset for a Droid DNA coming directly from HTC. I know that I could use an iFrame, but if HTC updates the URL, the iFrame is hosed. Is there a script in JS that will "scrape" these OEM sites automatically? I've seen plenty of examples in PHP, but looking for a solution in either HTML or JS.

Answer (score -1):

You can use javascript to make a GET request for the data.

Some links for doing this with jQuery:
http://api.jquery.com/load/ (see http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments)
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Note that relative links to assets may be broken, and if you're loading a whole page including  etc you should have it in an iframe. I don't see how this method is any better than using an iframe as it still won't work if the URL of the content changes.